# 404 error when submitting form

Tags: php

I keep getting a 404 error when trying to submit this form.  In my website directory i have a folder called `mobile`, which inside has `forms.php` and `process.php`.

The form is located on this page

```
http://localhost/mobile/forms.php?ft=0&id=2
```

here is the form

```
<form action='/mobile/process.php?o=9&ft=0' method='POST'>
//details
</form>
```

When i try to submit i get a 404 error, when it should go to `http://localhost/mobile/process.php?o=9&ft=0`?  How do i fix this?

Comment: If it doesn't go to `http://localhost/mobile/process.php?o=9&ft=0`, where *does* it go? What do the server logs say? What do you get if you go to the URL manually?

Comment: i get a 404 error is i go the URL manually?

Comment: What happens when you type `http://localhost/mobile/process.php?o=9&ft=0` directly into the browser URL field?

Comment: how do i check server logs?

Comment: 404 means the page is not found.  Are you 100% sure `http://localhost/mobile/process.php` exists?

Comment: @user892134 — Then you have the wrong URL. You check the server logs by opening whatever log files the (unspecified) server software you are running uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the URL's what I conclude is that both the php files are on the same page so change your action url from

```
<form action='/mobile/process.php?o=9&ft=0' method='POST'>
```

To

```
<form action='process.php?o=9&ft=0' method='POST'>
```

A forward slash before the `mobile` means it selects the folder from the root.. So you probably don't need that here.

Last but not the least, be sure the file names are proper, and also make sure the cases are same, because the file names are case sensitive.

> Note: You may also get 404 error if you are using `header('Location:
>   xyz.php');` on the form processing page, for redirecting the user to
>   some page after the form processes and you may encounter `404` because
>   the page on which the script has redirected doesn't exist. so make sure
>   that the URL is correct if you are using `header()`

Comment: i tried this and i still get a 404 error?  The process.php is in the mobile folder.

Comment: @user892134 both the files are in the same folder?

Comment: @user892134 As I told you, did you checked the file names? Also did you tried changing the action URL?

Comment: @user892134 LOL I knew it :D

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<form action='/mobile/process.php?o=9&ft=0' method='POST'>
```

to

```
<form action='process.php?o=9&ft=0' method='POST'>
```

Since they are in the same directory.

Comment: You can have params in the action like that.  It's a valid URL.  He's trying to send *both* GET and POST values.

Comment: Who said that you cannot pass the parameters in the URL?

Comment: Oh sorry, I was thinking POST. Sorry my bad! Edited the answer

Answer (score -1):

You can't pass a GET parameter in the form action.

In order to pass parameters, you will have to create a hidden input like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="o">
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you *can* send GET and POST by doing that.

Comment: You can pass GET parameters in the form action. And even if you couldn't it wouldn't give you a 404.

Comment: You CAN pass a `GET` parameter in a action field.  I often do, in combination with a `POST` method.

Comment: yeah, bad wording : i was meaning "you shouldn't"

Comment: @pierrito, I disagree with "you shouldn't".  Form data can be passed with `POST`, while informational data (such as what file the form was submitted from) can and should be sent via `GET`.

Comment: I was always told that using url parameters in the action for both POST and GET form was a bad idea. But i don't pretend to be a real specialist, so I trust you :)