# PHP redirect works in Chrome but not other browsers

Tags: php, forms

SO I am trying to learn myself MVC via the help of a book. **Im still at a very basic level** so please keep that in mind should you be kind enough to answer.

This is part of my application layout:

[image]

Now I have a simple login form

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
        <input type="text" name="action" value="login" style="display: none">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" required="required" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" />
        <br />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" required="required" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password" />
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
```

Note the first field `name="action" value="login"` since the redirect is dependent on that specific field.

**MODEL**

*users_db.php*

```
function login($email, $pword)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND pword = :pword ";
    $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':pword', $pword);
    $stmnt->execute();
    if ($stmnt->rowCount() > 0) {
        return $stmnt->fetchAll();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Directory - users**

index.php servers as controller. The following is a partial extract of the "controller" and is where the problem occurs.

```
require_once('../config/db.php');
require_once('../model/users_db.php');
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    if ($action == 'login') {
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
        $pword = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
        $users = login($email, $pword);
        if (is_array($users)) {
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['firstname'] = $user['firstname'];
                $_SESSION['lastname'] = $user['lastname'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
                $_SESSION['userType'] = $user['userType'];
                $_SESSION['userID'] = $user['userID'];
                header('Location:welcome.php');
                die();
            }
```

**APP FLOW / STEPS**

1. User enters email and password in the form.
2. Form info gets passed to index.php the "controller" which includes email, pword. and hidden input field value
3. Inside the index.php file the controller checks whether the hidden input field `action` value is set to login which it is.
4. If login is set it calls the login function from the users_db model, which queries db and returns all user info .
5. Assuming correct email & pword is enterd, index.php redirects user to a welcome page and `exit()`

The following works perfectly in Chrome but all other browsers redirects to a 404 error index.php not found. This is rather strange for me, would greatly appreciate it if anyone can provide some input as to why the above error occurs?

Comment: It looks like the issue is in form submission rather than in the redirection after setting session. After the error, can you go back and try to print the session to see what you see. If there is problem in redirection then the session should have been set already

Comment: Please check this post if that helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838408/404-error-when-submitting-form

Comment: first check if your post is executing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);


flush();
header("Location: http://www.website.com/");
echo '<script>window.location.replace("http://www.example.com")</script>';
die('should have redirected by now');
```

PHP redirects use header codes to tell the browser to redirect. But if your PHP code echo (even a warning) before that header location, some browsers won't redirect.

In the above code it flushes everything and send the header location. It also tell browser to redirect using javascript, so it will work even the php header redirect didn't work.

Hope it helps

Comment: ©Gijo, I think we need to find a way to fix it by PHP itself. We should also need to find the cause of this issue.

Comment: Thanks again @Gijo this still results in same problem im trying to inspect other causes and will update answer if / when I can get more information

Comment: The problem is not with the header redirect code. Some code above is wrong. That's the reason. Check it well

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one problems with that code, other than the redirection.
The reason why the `header` function doesn't work is because the header needs to have an absolute URL, like `http://www.example.com/replace.php`, besides that, there needs to be a space between the `Location:` header name and the value, like:

`header('Location: http://www.example.com/replace.php')`.

Note that in order to set a response header using the `header` function, **no previous headers should've been sent**, if you have anything as small as a space that is returned before you call the `header` function, it won't work.

Now, let's talk about the rest of the problems that this code has:

1 - The `session_start()` function needs to be called at the top of your page, way before you start working with the $_SESSION superglobal.

2 - You're calling `die()` in a foreach loop, meaning your code will iterate through the array only a single time and then the code will halt. Move the `die()` call outside of the loop.

3 - Validate the input using the `filter_val` function (http://php.net/manual/ro/function.filter-input.php) ~ I'm talking mostly about the email, but I think you can apply it to other inputs as well.

4 - Don't store the password in plain text format, use the password hashing API that PHP offers (https://www.sitepoint.com/hashing-passwords-php-5-5-password-hashing-api/)

Comment: Can you add ob_start() as point in your answer. It could be one of the possible issues

Comment: Instead of hacking the code with `ob_start()` and `ob_clean()` he should track down the culprit (If that's the case anyway).

Comment: Yes, I  agree. But is it not required to have ob_start() at the top to the header redirection to work?

Comment: Nope, you don't need to start the output buffer in order to set a header

Answer (score 0):

Possibly another solution:

> users_db.php

```
function login($email, $pword)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND pword = :pword LIMIT 1";
    $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $stmnt->bindValue(':pword', $pword);
    $stmnt->execute();
    if ($stmnt->rowCount() > 0) {
        return $stmnt->fetchAll();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

> index.php

```
    require_once('../config/db.php');
    require_once('../model/users_db.php');
    if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        if ($action == 'login') {
            $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
            $pword = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
            $user = login($email, $pword);
            if ($user != null) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $user['firstname'];
                    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $user['lastname'];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
                    $_SESSION['userType'] = $user['userType'];
                    $_SESSION['userID'] = $user['userID'];
                    header('Location: welcome.php');
                    echo '<script>window.location.replace("http://www.example.com")</script>';
                    die();
                }
             }
          }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your ongoing help. Unfortunately this solution results in same problem

Answer (score -1):

At the end die() function in foreach --> remove it and then try.

Answer (score -1):

Please check if your php code did not have error, and

look for white space after `:`

ex: `header('Location: welcome.php');`