# Getting 404 HTTP error on PHP contact form in HTML website hosted on Google App Engine

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine

I am getting a 404 HTTP error when I try to submit the form on my website. Everything else is working fine.

Below is my folder structure for my website. Inside my `www/index.html` file I have a form that uses `www/forms/contact.php` script which uses the library `www/assets/vendor/php-email-form/php-email-form.php`.

[image: Website Folder Structure]

Here is my `app.yaml` file:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1 
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: www/\1

- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

I tried modifying the `app.yaml` file to target the PHP script folder but still got the 404 HTTP error:

```
handlers:

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: forms/\1
```

Before I was using PHP 8.2 but rolled back to PHP 5.5 after realizing recent versions require a front controller. This has already given me enough headaches and I am about to give up on Google App Engine.

Comment: Can you try changing order of index.html to the first as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/q/897985/955887) and also check this [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54616748/18265570) and [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17838521/18265570).

Comment: Have you managed to check above comment?